# Azure web app automatically redirect from Http to Https

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a website on Azure and I have configured it with the custom domain.Website always redirects from http to https so getting error of not secure in browser as below..

[image]

I don't want to redirect it to https.What is the solution and what is the reason that it redirects to https ?

On azure in web app overview I get URL with Http :

[image]

Comment: You can't *not* want to use HTTPS anymore. Unless you want all browsers to mark your site as insecure, and disappear from Google results. Make sure your certificate and domain match.

Comment: Azure's move to mandatory HTTPS was requested by all users, announced in time, and the way to use a custom domain [is already documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate). Certificates from Lets Encrypt are free, and there is even a script that will manage certificate renewal automatically. There is no valid reason to remain to HTTP, and a lot of very good reasons to switch

Comment: What is the reason that it redirects to https ?I did nothing with that.It automatically redirects to https..@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Since I have configured custom domain only my machine's browsers can view that website using that url with **Not Secure** error where as on other Machine's browser, error occurs that web app not found..@PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Web Apps do not automatically redirect http to https by default, so it may be caused by some logic in your specific app, or some other non-default step that you took.

To see this, simply create a new empty Web App, and verify that you are able to browse to it using http.

Comment: Yeah , When I create new  web app I can able to browse to it with http.Does it mean I would have taken wrong step while creating WebApp for my website ?

Comment: Yes it likely means that it's caused by either some configuration or deployed content. Try a new deployment and check at what point out starts happening to help isolate