# custom domain in azure always redirect to https

Tags: azure, web-applications, dns, hosting

i have a problem with a custom domain in azure, i created a webapps and configurate the custom domain, the only https is disable

[image]

the hosting of domain is azure dns zone

when i try go to my page, always redirect to https
i did step by step from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

Comment: Do you have any redirects in place? What kind of app are you running in the Web App?

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its probaly that you have in your config this line

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web Apps do not automatically redirect http to https by default. It may be caused by some logic in your specific app.

Here is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610318/azure-web-app-automatically-redirect-from-http-to-https), you could refer to it.

> Azure Web Apps do not automatically redirect http to https by default, so it may be caused by some logic in your specific app, or some other non-default step that you took.
>
> To see this, simply create a new empty Web App, and verify that you are able to browse to it using http.